# Extend azure active directory access token claims

Tags: azure, authorization, azure-active-directory, access-token

I'm currently trying to authorize my api depending on the user group. After enabling the group claim in Azure Active Directory I have realized that the groups claim is not including in the access_token but the id_token.

I'm trying to avoid makings requests to the graph api and I've seen something about azure active directory claims mapping (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping)

But due to the lack of information and examples I'm not sure of how to deal with this.

Any suggestions on how to get the extra claims into the access token?

Comment: So you have an API, and the access token it gets does not contain the group ids?

Comment: Exactly, azure active directory provides the groups id only in the id_token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get group ids in access tokens too.

But the API app manifest must have:

```
{
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
}
```

Note that this must be in the APIs manifest, not the client app's manifest.

Comment: One caveat here (most probably a bug), if the Portal touches that file (add/remove permissions) after you add in `groupMembershipClaims`, it will just vanish and you have to manually put it back in. I'd strongly suggest calling into MS Graph API instead for group membership.

Answer (score 0):

In AAD, when you create an SSO application, you can create custom claims where you can customize the SAML response from AAD to the target application.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps#customizing-the-claims-issued-in-the-saml-token) for more information.